# Defining image mask based on image values G'MIC

Tags: image-processing, gimp, gmic

I am using the inpainting command in GMIC, which takes in both an image and a mask which indicates which part of that image to inpaint.  Values that are 255 on the mask are then filled in.

http://gmic.eu/reference.shtml

The input images I am using have huge black portions (the value of the pixels are 0 here).  I want to define the mask to be exactly the pixels of the original image which are black.

Of course, I can preprocess all these masks in matlab, python, etc, but this will take a long time as I am processing on the order of 1 million images.  GMIC has a fast piping interface which does everything in memory, and a mathematical interpreter, so I should be able to do this all with the GMIC command line and save a lot of time.

The answer I need does this entirely in GMIC using it's mathematical interpreter.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this probably :

```
$ gmic input.png --select_color 0,0,0,0 -inpaint[0] [1],.... -keep[0] -o output.png
```

(where you must set your inpaint parameters according to your needs).

Comment: I get 'Error encountered when calling G'MIC : '*** Error in ./ *** Unknown command or filename '--select_color'.'' Is there any alternate to select_color ?

Comment: @AkashGoyal try "-select_color" instead of "--select_color"